# Providing More information about DioException or DioErrors.?

Tags: flutter, exception, dio

I am using `Dio` package to make `API` calls in my Flutter app and I've implemented a custom error handler to deal with different types of errors. I'm getting the generic error message 'Something went wrong. Please try again'. How can I improve my error handling to provide more specific information to the user for this type of error?

```
static String handleError(error) {
    String errorDescription = '';
    if (error is DioException) {
      DioException dioError = error;
      switch (dioError.type) {
        case DioExceptionType.cancel:
          errorDescription = 'Request to API server was cancelled';
          break;
        case DioExceptionType.connectionTimeout:
          errorDescription = 'Connection timeout with API server';
          break;
        case DioExceptionType.unknown:
          errorDescription = 'Please check your internet connection';
          break;
        case DioExceptionType.receiveTimeout:
          errorDescription = 'Receive timeout in connection with API server';
          break;
        case DioExceptionType.badResponse:
          errorDescription = 'Something went wrong. Please try again';
          break;
        case DioExceptionType.sendTimeout:
          errorDescription = 'Send timeout in connection with API server';
          break;
        case DioExceptionType.badCertificate:
         errorDescription = 'Unexpected error occured';
          break;
        case DioExceptionType.connectionError:
          errorDescription = 'Unexpected error occured';
          break;
      }
    } else {
      errorDescription = 'Unexpected error occured';
    }
    return errorDescription;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use this code if you encounter the generic error message 'Something went wrong. Please try again'.

Here are some ways to make your error handling better when you get the **DioExceptionType.badResponse**. These suggestions will help give users clearer information about what's going wrong.

```
case DioExceptionType.badResponse:
try {
    // Check for specific status codes and provide tailored messages
    if (dioError.response!.statusCode == 404) {
      errorDescription = 'Resource not found';
    } else if (dioError.response!.statusCode == 401) {
      errorDescription = 'Unauthorized access';
    } else if (dioError.response!.statusCode == 422) {
      errorDescription = 'Validation failed';
      try {
        // Parse error details from response body (if available)
        final parsedError = jsonDecode(dioError.response!.data);
        // Use parsedError for more specific messages
      } catch (e) {
        // Handle potential JSON decoding errors gracefully
      }
    } else {
      errorDescription = 'Something went wrong. Please try again';
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle any errors while accessing response properties
  }
  break;
```

Comment: Yes this is working fine @naman